# Signalr Hub method not invoked when msg sent through postman (multiple hubs)

Tags: websocket, signalr, signalr-hub

When I send a message through postman to invoke my server method, it does not get invoked.

I have multiple signalr hubs.
One of my hubs "ChatHub" has a method call "SendMessage" that takes in 2 parameters (string)

I have tried on postman:

1. Negotiate to chathub
   [image]
2. Made a connection to chathub
   [image]
3. Sent the handshake: {"protocol": "json", "version": 1}
4. Sent my msg: {"type": 1, "target": "SendMessage", "arguments": ["Test", "Test Message"]}

But my server method does not get invoked.

I've encoded my json msg with chr(0x1e)

Any clue as to what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the message format should be like the below based on network traffic:

{"H":"chathub","M":"SendMessage","A":["vivian", "hello"], "I":3}